# Creating a common javascript function in the Rails Asset Pipeline

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have a Rails app with the following javascript asset structure

```
|- app
  |- assets
    |- javascripts
      |- articles
        - index.js
        - show.js
      - application.js
```

The `application.js` file seems to be a manifest of all files

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require react
//= require react_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

Let's say I have some common function `foo()` that I want to be accessible globally (from both `index.js` and `show.js`)

```
function foo() {
  // do cool stuff here
}
```

How do i go about creating a common JS file with common/shared functions like this? Specifically, where should the file be created and how should it be incorporated into the manifest? And how will it be compiled when compiling assets in production?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can make new file called `common.js` and require it before `index.js` and `show.js` in manifest file

**app/assets/javascripts/common.js**

```
function foo() {
  // do cool stuff here
}
```

**app/assets/javascripts/application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require react
//= require react_ujs
//= require common
//= require_tree .
```

The order of assets precompile will follow the order of your manifest file.